# Unterminated String Literal Error in Firebug

Tags: javascript, php

I am getting error in Firefox `SyntaxError: unterminated string literal` when i try to include following code:

```
<script>
 function makeProdiv(data){
       var tbl_body = "";
       var tbl_row = "";
       tbl_row +="<?php foreach($data as $row) {} ?>" (Error at this line)
       tbl_body += tbl_row;
       return tbl_body;
 }
</script>
```

If i remove this row then error disappears.

What i am trying: I am trying to loop through the result returned from DB and display values.

Please anyone can assist?

Comment: In  your case, PHP is server-side and JavaScript is client-side. If your PHP code reaches the browser, there's something wrong on your server setup (or you don't even have a server).

Comment: Is the body of the `foreach` really empty, or did you just decide not to copy it here?

Comment: working good for me.without any error.

Comment: @Barmar. it is long piece of code. So i decided not to include here as with or withoyt body i am getting same error

Comment: @user3909577 — You have a client side error. Show us the client side code you generate, not (a gutted version of) the server side code that generates it.

Answer (score 2):

You most likely have double quotes in the content generated by PHP. You need to escape them properly, or, providing you don't have single quotes in the PHP content, you could do:

```
tbl_row +='<?php foreach($data as $row) { /* ... */} ?>';
```

As noted in the comments, having newlines in your PHP content might also cause this issue. Remove or replace them.

Comment: Maybe also if he has newlines in the content, since JS doesn't allow newlines in strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<?php foreach ($data as $row) { ?>
    tbl_row += <?php echo json_encode(whatever); ?>;
<?php } ?>
```

Using `json_encode()` will ensure that the PHP value is correctly encoded for Javascript.

Comment: Then you need to post more code, so we can see what you're actually doing that's causing the problem. And I don't believe you when you say that you got the error with an empty loop body.

Comment: @Barmar That makes two of us.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
      <?php foreach($data as $row) {?>
        tbl_row +=<?php echo $row;?>
      <? }?>
```

what it contain?the 
'data' that is passed to this function "makeProdiv(data)"
& $data.

I guess $data is an array of "tr" fetched from db.

Comment: Don't just post uncommented code - explain why it's a solution.